# how to print the loop value outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written on for loop in one function. And I stored all values in one variable. If I print alert on that variable i got list of datas. And I have another function. I want to print the first function loop datas in second function.

```
$.each(function(i, val) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        var value = data[i];
        alert(value);
    }
});


var addHoldAccordiaonChckBx = function() {
    alert(value);
}
```

I want to print the all loop values in second function. Please help me for do this.

Comment: You're not storing all values in one variable. You are **replacing** it in every loop.

Comment: I want to store all values in one variable. And pass that all values in another function. Please help me for do this.

Comment: @sathishkumar check my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Add the value into an array and print the array in your second function, The code would be like below. Also remove your unnecessary `$.each` loop, its not required as you already have a for loop inside it.

```js
var data =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  //for demo

var value = [];   // create an array

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    value.push(data[i]);        //push data into the array
}


var addHoldAccordiaonChckBx = function() {
  //alert(value.toString());  
  // value contains all the values pushed in the first function loop
  $('div').append(value.toString());
}

addHoldAccordiaonChckBx(); // call your second function.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value; 

$.each(function(i, val) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        value += data[i];
        alert(value);
    }
});

var addHoldAccordiaonChckBx = function() {
   alert(value);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$.each(function(i, val) {
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

 var value += data[i];

  alert(data[i]);

}
});


var addHoldAccordiaonChckBx = function(){

  alert(value);

  }
```

Comment: You're still redefining `value` on every loop in this example, and it will have gone out of scope by the time `addHoldAccordiaonChckBx` is called - the variable needs to be defined outside the `$.each`, as in Alex C's answer.